# Arduino LCD Brightness

Tags: lcd

I've made this small device that uses a ultrasonic sensor to tell how far away an object is and display it on a 16x2 display.

Here's the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int Contrast=100;
 LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int trigPin = 7;
const int echoPin = 8;
// defining variables
long duration;
int distance;
void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
  analogWrite(6, Contrast);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();  
}
void loop() {

// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
distance = duration / 29 / 2;
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
Serial.print("Distance: ");
Serial.println(distance);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Distance: ");

 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(distance);
  delay(100);
  lcd.clear();
}
```

Every thing works fine apart from the fact that the lcd backlight is too dim(barely visible). I tried looking online but is there any way i can get max brightness without a potentiometer? I do have resistors , can i use them somehow?

Comment: Please share your wiring diagram so we can help you. Contract control is usually done using a potentiometer, but can vary depending on the LCD model.

Answer (score 1):

The back light of the LCD is just an LED connected through a resistors on the A (15) and K (16) pins on the display. The LED doesn't require an external resistor since according to the [datasheet](https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/eone-1602a1.pdf) there is a build in resistor on the board itself. If you aren't using any external resistors and applying a constant voltage of 5V and the screen is still dim than this means that the led is most likely dead and you would need to replace the back light panel.

If you are talking about the contrasts of the display. Than I would recommend you to hook up the contrast pin to a PWM pin on the Arduino and by using `analogWite` to tune the display in order to get the desired value of contrast.

Comment: Most character LCDs have a series resistor but not all. It is a manufacturing option, Typically LCDs available for the hobby market do, but this should be confirmed prior to use.